# At which point are the constructors of base classes called in a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization-list

I need to know when the constructors of basis classes are called in the call of a derived class constructor.

```
Small example:

class Base1
{...}

class Base2
{...}

class Derived : Base1,Base2
{...}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
Derived Child;
}
```

With the command `Derived Child;` the constructor of `Derived` is called, but I have read that before the `Derived` class constructor is executed all base constructors are executed, i.e. constructors of Base1 and Base2.

So I am wondering how the event order would be if the constructor of class `Derived` looked like this

```
Derived::Derived (Parameters)
:                      //initialization list
Base2 (Parameters)
{...}
```

Is the constructor of class `Base2` now called in the initialazation list of constructor `Derived` or is it called before. Furthermore are all base class constructors called at the beginning of the call of constructor `Derived` or when the initialization list of class `Derived` constructor starts.

greetings 
streight

Comment: fyi, it's *base* class, not *basis* class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of call of constructors is 1st Base class then derived class.

In current example 
Order of call of constructors is as :
Basis1
Basis2
Derived

If we change class definition to

class Derived : Basis2,Basis1

then order of constructor calls will be:
Basis2
Basis1
Derived

Base class constructor are always called before derived class, whether called explicitly from initialization list or not.

Comment: So, the initialization of a base constructor is used instantly for the call of the base constructor? Does the compiler first read the initialization list before calling the base constructors?

Comment: check this code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1xNtnsgZBdpZXZ3TEhpUTFoRVk/edit?usp=sharing, the output of the program clearly shows that base class ctr are invoked first and then initialization list processed.

Comment: Last questions: 1. I have changed your code into http://www.file-upload.net/download-8335688/main.cpp.html
Why do I get the output `x :2` ?                                        2.Will base constructors be called multiple times when also initialized in initializing list?

Comment: I am getting error when I compile your file :test.cpp:24:5: error: multiple initializations given for base ‘Basis1'

Comment: Ok, now it works :). You have to change your constructor of derived into `Derived(int y):Basis2(),Basis1(6) ...`. My bad :). The result is that OF class Basis1 only the second Basis1(int x) constructor of initialisation list is called. Therefore the compiler must have read the initialization list before starting the base constructors, I guess thats the general mechanism: 1. Reading the initialisation list 2.Initialise base constructors, 3. Initialize derived constructor